# How to mix Java Servlets with Play framework web-sockets?

Tags: java, scala, servlets, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to mix a standard J2EE app and Play web-sockets. Both are written in Scala.

I managed to get the Play web-socket code to compile with my J2EE Scala code by including some of the jars from the Play framework distribution. However, I am not able to figure out how to get Play's web-socket handler to listen to connections.
I usually run the app using Jetty (`java -jar jetty-runner.jar myapp.war`)

I don't mind running the app via `play run` as long as I can use both the Servlets and Play's web-socket.

Is there any better solution than running the two apps in separate containers?

The J2EE app uses HTML, JSP, Servlets and JDBC.

Comment: Can you expand on your motivation? The easiest way would be to keep your applications separate and have nginx give a "unified HTTP front" across all your HTTP servers.

Comment: @AndrewE I have a fully developed J2EE app and I want to add some websocket functionality to it. I prefer Play's code for this rather than alternatives because its very clean. However, I don't want to Play'ify my entire app as that would require too much effort.

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't suggest play-ifying your entire app, rather just keep the core competencies where they are: your J2EE app stays as it is and add a new small Play websocket app alongside. Use nginx in front so callers hit one host:port; some URIs are directed to J2EE and some to Play/WS. Granted there are pros and cons with this, but it keeps things simple, separate and clear.

Comment: @AndrewE Then there is issue of how the two will communicate. The web-app generates the data, which the websocket needs to push. So I will have to make an interface between the two (which is doable with some effort).

Comment: True enough. But a few thoughts (FWIW): should the web-app definitely produce the data, not a third service? If the long term architecture is a third service (ie producing data may not really be what the web-app should do) then it could push msgs to rabbitmq, and the "live update app" (play) listens on mq and sends via websockets. If that's the case then an interim arch could be the web-app sends updates via mq.
I grant you, this is a bit more than you need right now, but I like to be guided by "space invaders": shoot where the problem is going, not here it is right now!

Answer (score 1):

Play uses sbt for it's build system. I'd say the easiest way achieve your goal woudld work the other way around by sticking with sbt for compiling and building both - the Servelet project and the play2 project. Sbt compiles scala and java sources just fine if the directories are [configured properly](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Directories.html). As play2 already generates [a proper sbt build config](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Build) all you need is to hook up a servlet build config into it. Sbt has several plugins for special tasks and in this case you can use the [x-sbt-webplugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin).